# how to remove Container and Template form widgets layout update field?

Tags: magento2, widgets

[image]

As Shown Image Want To Remove Container And Template

Comment: may I ask why??

Comment: I don't need of both so i want to remove if any idea how to remove plz replay

Comment: By removing you are trying to break how widgets work. It doesn't look like a simple task.

Comment: /opt/lampp/htdocs/magentovdc/vendor/magento/module-widget/view/adminhtml/templates/instance/edit/layout.phtml  It's Come Form This File So Tell How to Remove It.                    Note:When Remove From Magento file It does Not Show So How I can Implement In My Module.Thanks In Advance